# how to search and retrun value from array

Tags: javascript

Trying, find and return a value from array using JavaScript- with dynamic inputs

```
const drawers = [
  {
    "name": "locations",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "dana-point-ca",
        "label": "Dana Point, CA"
      },
      {
        "value": "bronx-new-york",
        "label": "Bronx, New York"
      },
      {
        "value": "new-york-ny",
        "label": "New York, NY"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "programAreas",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "coral-conservation",
        "label": "CORAL CONSERVATION"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Input keys are dynamic, if it is locations and value is bronx-new-york  then it should return `Bronx, New York`;

```
let lbl = drawers.find(o => o.name === 'string 1').label;
```

Comment: you'll need to search for `bronx-new-york` in `o.values` array

Comment: `let lbl = drawers.map(o=>o.values.find(o=>o.value==='string 1')).filter(x=>x)?.[0]?.label;`

Comment: Inputs is dynamic

Comment: yes, it is, so what? you said what the input string was - then your code looks for `string 1` - so your question is nonsense

Comment: Can input be "coral-conservation"?

Comment: Correct it can be

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.find` in each values until you find the answer.

```js
const drawers = [
  {
    "name": "locations",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "dana-point-ca",
        "label": "Dana Point, CA"
      },
      {
        "value": "bronx-new-york",
        "label": "Bronx, New York"
      },
      {
        "value": "new-york-ny",
        "label": "New York, NY"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "programAreas",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "coral-conservation",
        "label": "CORAL CONSERVATION"
      }
    ]
  }
]

function getLabel(x) {
  for (const nameValues of drawers) {
    const values = nameValues.values
    const item = values.find(v => v.value === x)
    if (item !== undefined) {
      return item.label
    }
  }  
}

getLabel("bronx-new-york")  // 'Bronx, New York'
getLabel("coral-conservation")  // 'CORAL CONSERVATION'
getLabel("Value that does not exist") // undefined
```

Comment: Question updated

Comment: This answer should still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < drawers.length ; i++){
    let lbl = drawers[i].values.find(o => o.label === "Bronx, New York").label;
    console.log(lbl)
}
```

Comment: Question updated

Comment: only find should be used ?

Comment: Add `if(lbl) break;` will improve performance

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways to achieve that. As below, you will get all the possible results. However, you might need to deconstruct the arrays in order to get the strings.

```
const drawers = [
  {
    "name": "locations",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "dana-point-ca",
        "label": "Dana Point, CA"
      },
      {
        "value": "bronx-new-york",
        "label": "Bronx, New York"
      },
      {
        "value": "new-york-ny",
        "label": "New York, NY"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "programAreas",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "coral-conservation",
        "label": "CORAL CONSERVATION"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const enteredValue = "bronx-new-york";
const resultArrays = []

const onSearchLocation = () => {
 drawers.find(location => {
    const labels = location.values.map((place => { 
      const array = [];
      if(place.value === enteredValue) {
          array.push(place.label);
      } 
      
      if(array.length > 0) {
          resultArrays.push(array);
      }
     }
   ))
  })}

onSearchLocation();

console.log(resultArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use find with combination of map.

```js
const d = [
  {
    "name": "locations",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "dana-point-ca",
        "label": "Dana Point, CA"
      },
      {
        "value": "bronx-new-york",
        "label": "Bronx, New York"
      },
      {
        "value": "new-york-ny",
        "label": "New York, NY"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "programAreas",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "coral-conservation",
        "label": "CORAL CONSERVATION"
      }
    ]
  }
]

let r = d.find(el => el.name === 'locations').values
let re = r.map(v => {
  if (v.value == 'bronx-new-york') {
    return v.label
  }
})
result = re.filter(e => e)
console.log(result)
```